# Ansible prompt to verify selected hosts

Tags: ansible

I am running intrusive tasks on multiple hosts and want to take caution to make sure the tasks are ONLY run on specified hosts. To avoid accidentally running on the incorrect hosts I want the user to be prompted to confirm inventory selection. Is it possible for Ansible to prompt and lists the hosts the user selected based on an inventory group or pattern match and ask for confirmation before continuing?

**Example:**

**Inventory:**

```
[east_servers]
server_a
server_b
server_c

[west_servers]
server_d
server_e
server_f
```

**Playbook Run:**

```
ansible-playbook -l east playbooks/my_playbook.yml
```

**Example Playbook:**

```
---
  - hosts: all
    vars_prompt:
      - name: Confirm host selection
        prompt: "You have selected hosts server_a, server_b, server_c from hosts group east_servers. 
                 Do you want to continue?"
        private: no

    tasks: # If user prompt = "yes" continue else exit.

    - name: Task 1
    - name: Task 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do pretty much exactly what you're showing in your question.  For example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: confirm
      prompt: >-
        You have selected {{ ansible_play_batch }}. Do you want
        to continue?
  tasks:
    - name: check for confirmation
      fail:
      when: confirm.lower() != 'y'

    - name: example task
      ping:
```

The `ansible_play_batch` variable contains the list of hosts involved in the current play. We use that in the `prompt` argument of the `vars_prompt` section to set the `confirm` variable, and then we have a `fail` task in the playbook that fails when `confirm` is not `y`.

Running the playbook looks like this when answer `y` to the prompt:

```
Script started on 2020-06-12 08:36:00-04:00 [TERM="dumb" TTY="/dev/pts/14" COLUMNS="94" LINES="63"]
You have selected ['server a', 'server b', 'server c']. Do you want to continue?:

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [check for confirmation] ****************************************************************
skipping: [server a]
skipping: [server b]
skipping: [server c]

TASK [example task] **************************************************************************
ok: [server b]
ok: [server a]
ok: [server c]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
server a                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
server b                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
server c                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Or like this when answer `n`:

```
Script started on 2020-06-12 08:36:35-04:00 [TERM="dumb" TTY="/dev/pts/14" COLUMNS="94" LINES="63"]
You have selected ['server a', 'server b', 'server c']. Do you want to continue?:

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [check for confirmation] ****************************************************************
fatal: [server a]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed as requested from task"}
fatal: [server b]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed as requested from task"}
fatal: [server c]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed as requested from task"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
server a                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server b                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server c                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```